# Scrapy with many spiders

Tags: scrapy

I have one project where I need scraped data from different sites. Example: I scraped site 1, then I check some conditions (check  DB, etc.), and if those conditions are true, I need to run another spider for the next site and pass data scraped on first site. What project architecture (combination of spiders and pipelines) is best to this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To launch another Spider from one Spider in Scrapy is impossible

I had such requirement once and what I did is that I used `ScrapyD`, whenever I needed to launch another Spider, I just sent a request using `requests.get('to_your_scrapyd:6800/schedule.json?project=project&spider=spider')` or `scrapy.Request` and the new Spider would run